# ConditionalWeakTable how to use in unity3d project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx) says that `ConditionalWeakTable` is in the  `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace, but there is no definition of it in this namespace. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Dude you're a Unity programmer now.  Not a .Net programmer.  Get used to it.  :)

Comment: Dictionary of WeakReferences it is then Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All current versions of unity use a restricted set of .NET 3.5. `ConditionalWeakTable` was introduced in .NET 4.0

If you look [at their roadmap](https://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap) updating the version of Mono for the runtime they use is in the development stage and updating the .NET profile they use is still in the research phase.

Comment: then why was it given in a answer about unity over at gamedev.stackexchange ?

Comment: Because maybe the person answering doesn't use Unity and was answering in general not Unity specific? Or I am overlooking something and you can use it but I don't know how.

Comment: I think that some parts of c# 4 are in the unity version. Like optional/named parameters are. Not sure about `ConditionalWeakTable` though. It's all very confusing.

Comment: Named parameters are a compiler feature, not a .NET version feature. You can use named parameters in .NET 2.0 if you are compiling with a compiler that supports it. Make sure to separate in your mind C# 4 from .NET 4.

Comment: ah, misunderstanding on my part